# Highchart graph inside leaflet popup using geojson data and oneachfeature

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, leaflet, geoserver

Fist of all, I am fairly new to javascript so I am still trying to learn, please bear with me.  I am trying to create a map using leaflet that brings in a JSONP layer using WFS from geoserver on my localhost.  I have successfully added the layer to the map and can use oneachfeature function to get feature properties upon clicking.

Now I what to create a highchart basic area graph that opens inside a popup, or a new window, that uses several feature properties from the geoJSON where clicked. I am struggling to understand the popup div and when the highchart actually gets created.  Right now as I have it the popup opens a highchart graph in the popup window, but it is also behind the base map tile as I can see it if I pan across my map, before the base tiles finish loading.  I also notice that the highchart graph does not appear to use the tooltip options such as hover.  I suspect that I am not setting up or calling on my div correctly.   Here is the relevant part of my code.

```
<body>
<div id="map">  
<div id="chartcontainer" class="highchart">
</div>      
<script>


    //URL for the WFS JSONP output from geoserver
    var URL = "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/Capstone/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=Capstone:TrinityJSON&outputFormat=text/javascript&format_options=callback:getJson";

    //ajax to call the WFS from geoserver and add JSON to map
    var WFSLayer = null;
    var ajax = $.ajax({
        url : URL,
        dataType : 'jsonp',
        jsonpCallback : 'getJson',
        success : function (response) {
            WFSLayer = L.geoJson(response, {
                style: function (feature) {
                    return {
                        stroke: false,
                        fillColor: 'FFFFFF',
                        fillOpacity: 0.1
                    };
                },
                //onEachFeature used to create popup using the JSON data.  
                onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                    layer.on('click', function(e){

                    var chartplotoptions ={
                        chart: {
                            type: 'area'
                        },
                        title: {
                            text: 'Aquifer Units'
                        },

                        xAxis: {
                            allowDecimals: false,
                            labels: {
                                formatter: function () {
                                    return this.value; 
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        yAxis: {
                                startOnTick: false,
                                minPadding: 0.05,
                            title: {
                                text: 'Elevation from Sea Level (ft)',

                            },
                            labels: {
                                formatter: function () {
                                    return this.value ;
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        tooltip: {
                            pointFormat: '{series.name}{point.y}'
                        },
                        plotOptions: {

                                area: {
                                pointStart: 0,
                                threshold: 657,
                                marker: {
                                    enabled: false,
                                    symbol: 'circle',
                                    radius: 2,
                                    states: {
                                        hover: {
                                            enabled: true
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        series: [{
                            name: 'Surface',
                            data: [parseFloat(feature.properties.Top1),parseFloat(feature.properties.Top1)]
                        }, 

                        ]
                    };


                    $('#chartcontainer').highcharts(chartplotoptions);
                    layer.bindPopup($('#chartcontainer').html());
                    layer.openPopup();  
                    });
                }
            }).addTo(map);
        }
    });

</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Catch `L.Map`'s `popupopen` event, it fires when a popup up is opened. That's when it's content get attached to the DOM, so that's when you need to initialize your chart:

```
new L.Marker([0, 0]).bindPopup('<div></div>').addTo(map);

map.on('popupopen', function (e) {
    console.log(e.popup._source); // Marker instance
    console.log(e.popup._contentNode); // Popup content element
});
```

So in your case, all you need to do in the `onEachFeature` method is initialize the popup and attach it to the layer:

```
new L.GeoJSON(url, {
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        layer.bindPopup('<div></div>');
    }
}).addTo(map);
```

Now when a feature gets clicked, the popup opens (it's default behaviour, you don't have to use the `click` event) the `div` gets attached to the DOM and the `popupopen` event fires on your `L.Map` instance. In the handler you have access to the layer that was clicked and the popup's content `div` element. That's when you need to do your highchart stuff:

```
map.on('popupopen', function (e) {
    console.log(e.popup._source); // Layer instance
    console.log(e.popup._source.feature); // Layer's feature 
    console.log(e.popup._contentNode); // Popup content element

    // Do highchart stuff with your element and feature data.
});
```

Comment: thank you, but perhaps I don't understand how to fit this to my code.  I don't need a marker either.  Do you mind explaining how to incorporate with oneachfeature and highcharts?

Comment: Elaborated a little more in my answer, if you'de add a [mcve] to you question i could give you an example.